# Проблемы с Microsoft::DirectX::AudioVideoPlayback::Video

Tags: c++-cli, directx

Пишу в C++ WinForms.

Добавляю в проект reference "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\DirectX for Managed Code\1.0.2902.0\Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback.dll"

```
namespace MyProgram {
    //...
    using namespace Microsoft::DirectX::AudioVideoPlayback;

    public ref class MainWindow : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        MainWindow(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Video^ v = gcnew Video("1.mp4", false);
            v->Owner = this->pictureBox1;
            v->Play();
        }
    };
}
```

Запускаю. Проект запустился, но окно не появляется. Как будто словил бесконечный цикл.
Ставлю Breakpoint на InitializeComponent(). Вообще в конструктор не заходит.
Если удалить код из конструктора, кроме InitializeComponent, проект работает.
Выполняю этот код в другой функции. Опять ставлю Breakpoint на InitializeComponent():

```
MainWindow(void)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    func();
}

void func() {
    Video^ v = gcnew Video("1.mp4", false);
    v->Owner = this->pictureBox1;
    v->Play();
}
```

Словил этот Breakpoint. Но на вызове функции func() застыл.
Как исправить этот баг?

**Обновление**

Даже если вместо:

```
Video^ v = gcnew Video("1.mp4", false);
v->Owner = this->pictureBox1;
v->Play();
```

сделать:

```
Type^ t = Type::GetType("Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback.Video", true);
```

вылетит исключение:

```
Could not load type 'Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback.Video' from assembly 'PictureEditor, Version=1.0.5386.26557, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Video^ v = gcnew Video("1.mp4", false);
v->Owner = this->pictureBox1;
v->Play();
```

Попробуйте вызывать не в конструкторе, а в методе Load вашей формы.

Comment: Не помогло.